# Modify exiting email instead of making a new one

Tags: mysql

I should modify the existing email by discarding everything after @ from the existing email address (or taking only the initial part of the email address to the @ sign) and adding iths.edu.rs.
This one is wrong because it creates new email.

```
SELECT fname,lname,email,CONCAT(LOWER(fname),'.',LOWER(lname), '@iths.edu.rs') AS 'new_email'
FROM employee
WHERE 
(LEFT(fname,1)='s' OR LEFT(lname,1)='s') 
AND email IS NOT NULL
```

This is what I get
[image: This is what I get]

These are expected results
[image: This is what I should get]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to `update` the table:

```
UPDATE employee
SET email = CONCAT(LOWER(fname),'.',LOWER(lname), '@iths.edu.rs')
WHERE (LEFT(fname,1)='s' OR LEFT(lname,1)='s') AND email IS NOT NULL
```

I'm not sure about the condition:

```
(LEFT(fname,1)='s' OR LEFT(lname,1)='s')
```

but I left it there because you use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this to show only people whose emails have been changed. This was my task.

```
UPDATE employee
SET email = CONCAT(LOWER(fname),'.',LOWER(lname), '@iths.edu.rs')
WHERE (LEFT(fname,1)='s' OR LEFT(lname,1)='s') AND email IS NOT NULL;

SELECT fname,lname,email
FROM employee
WHERE (LEFT(fname,1)='s' OR LEFT(lname,1)='s') AND email IS NOT NULL
```